# Is it possible to short this style code?

Tags: css, less

Is it possible to short this style lines?

```
.panel-body {
  height: ~"calc(100vh - 295px)";
  padding: 15px 0 !important;
  & > .row {
    height: 100%;
    & > div {
      height: 100%;
      & > .tab-content {
        height: 100%;
        & > .tab-pane {
          height: 100%;
          & > .row {
            height: 100%;
              & > .class-1 {
                height: 100%;
                & > .class-2 {
                  height: 100%;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This is in Less. So maybe is any solution to short this lines code.
I don't know how to do this, so will be nice to get some help :)

Comment: That very much depends on what HTML this gets applied to in the first place. Please provide a proper [mcve].

Comment: If i good understand - i add proper.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. With the exact same behaviour (independently of your html) probably not. But depending on your actual layout, you may try something like `& > .row { & *: { height: 100%}}`. But if you provide html and a brief explanation of what you are trying to do, then we would probably understand better the problem to help you.

Comment: So i wont this height: 100%; only to this class-2 element. Inside this class-2 are 3 another calsses like .row > col-sm-... etc.

Comment: Overnesting at its best. As already commented it's impossible to suggest anything better w/o knowing what exactly this code is supposed to do (what HTML it's to be applied to, what are `class-1,2` are for etc.). But the it is thi is not just "not short" it's simply awful. Just a perfect example of how to never write any CSS-preprocessor (not just Less) code.

Comment: @seven-phases-max And I would bet that the HTML is overnested, too

Comment: Either way to not sound unfounded: what you really mean there is just something like `.panel-body * {height: 100%}` (like bitifet suggested but shorter). It's yet again hard to say if that would fit your particular HTML and your particular goal, but you really should learn more pure CSS design patterns first (stacking all these `>` and `{}` is not a good start).

Answer (score 1):

If the `panel-body` is having a fixed defined height `calc(100vh - 295px)` and you are cascading `height:100%` so why not simply adding the fixed height to the last element:

```
.class-2  {
   height:calc(100vh - 295px);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Make a class ( .height-100 )

```
.height-100{ height:100%; }
```

and add to your html elements

Comment: This solution i did before this post, but im searching for another solution.

Comment: Please do not add stuff like “Follow to my instagram page: ...” to your answers here. This isn’t a place to promote your stuff. You can put a link to your project on your profile if you want, but it doesn’t belong _here_. https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion